# Как отделить домен и адрес сайта от полной ссылки?

Tags: php, url

Есть переменная с URL:

```
$url = "http://victorpavloff.tmweb.ru/works/ElenaBeauty/";
```

Как с помощью регулярных выражений вытащить адрес сайта и домен?

Например, чтобы поучилось

```
$site = http://victorpavloff.tmweb.ru/
$domain = victorpavloff.tmweb.ru
```

Comment: Зачем регулярки если есть `parse_url()`? Или тот же `explode()`

Answer (score 2):

```
$url = parse_url('http://victorpavloff.tmweb.ru/works/ElenaBeauty/');
[$site, $domain] = [$url['scheme'] . '://' . $url['host'], $url['host']];

var_dump($site, $domain);
```

https://3v4l.org/HcO31

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "http://victorpavloff.tmweb.ru/works/ElenaBeauty/";

$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
printf("%s\n%s\n", $parsedUrl['scheme'].'://'.$parsedUrl['host'], $parsedUrl['host']);

$matches = [];
preg_match('/(?<url>((?<scheme>http+s?)(:\/\/)+)(?<host>.*?))(?<path>\/.*$)/i', $url, $matches);
printf("\n%s\n%s\n", $matches['url'], $matches['host']);
```